# Are universal Turing machines universal in the sense of category theory?

Tags: category-theory, turing-machines, universal-property

I just read the following (paraphrased) definition of universal Turing machine (UTM): “a UTM $M$ has the property that for any other Turing machine $N$ there is an invertible map $f$ from the set of possible states of the tape of $N$ into the set of possible states of the tape $M$ such that if we apply $f$ to an input string of $N$, run the image string on $M$ until it halts then apply the inverse map we get exactly the output of $N$ on that string.”

To me (a category theory novice) this sounds almost like a universal property, so I’m wondering if there is a category where universality as a Turing machine is given by some universal property. I’m guessing one issue is that there should also be some uniqueness statement in the definition, which is noticeably absent.

Comment: Hint: universal properties in category theory always include a uniqueness statement.

Comment: it may be worth looking into the Turing Category which I just skimed in the morning https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2019/08/turing_categories.html and the paper Introduction to Turing Categories by Hofstra and Cockett https://di.ens.fr/users/longo/files/Cockett-TuringCateg.pdf . And in the paper, the authors mention that "Turing category ... are supposed to give a minimal setting in which the Universality Theorem and the Parameter Theorem hold."